# Beam Search Decoder Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking to implement a sequence to sequence neural net with attention and beam search in Tensorflow 2.0 alpha. While the tutorials on their website have been very useful, I am having trouble figuring out the best way to implement beam search since the contrib library is deprecated - can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried to use TF2.0s upgrade script to upgrade my tensorflow 1.X beam search to 2.0, but it does not support the contrib library.

This is how the  beam search code looked for 1.x

```py
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder(
                    cell=decoder_cell,
                    embedding=self.embeddings,
                    start_tokens=tf.fill([self.batch_size], tf.constant(2)),
                    end_token=tf.constant(3),
                    initial_state=initial_state,
                    beam_width=self.beam_width,
                    output_layer=self.projection_layer
                )
outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(
                    decoder, output_time_major=True, maximum_iterations=summary_max_len, scope=decoder_scope)
self.prediction = tf.transpose(outputs.predicted_ids, perm=[1, 2, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Few of the Tensorflow 1.x APIs are moved to different APIs in Tensorflow 2.x.
Tf.contrib is one such library which partly moved to Tensorflow addons.

For the `tf.contrib.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder` is moved to `tfa.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder in TFv2.x.`

```
tfa.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder(
    cell: tf.keras.layers.Layer,
    beam_width: int,
    embedding_fn: Optional[Callable] = None,
    output_layer: Optional[tf.keras.layers.Layer] = None,
    length_penalty_weight: tfa.types.FloatTensorLike = 0.0,
    coverage_penalty_weight: tfa.types.FloatTensorLike = 0.0,
    reorder_tensor_arrays: bool = True,
    **kwargs
)
```